# Handling multiple Requests and return just one

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, request

I get multiple POST requests from frontend app in chunks. For example one chunk can store 5 files, and if frontend app is sending 10 files to me it means it sends 2 chunks of files == 2 requests. I want to grab this 2 requests and create a single PDF file from them. Now my code is making 2 separated PDFs instead of 1 PDF.

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("exportToPdf")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePdf([FromQuery] string colorMode, [FromQuery] string? textOrPath)
    {
        try
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task<byte[]>>();

            foreach (var svgFile in Request.Form.Files)
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    return _pdfGeneratorService.GeneratePdfFromSvgFile(svgFile, colorMode, textOrPath);
                });
                tasks.Add(task);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            var pdfPages = tasks.Select(task => task.Result).ToList();

            var finalPdfBytes = MergePages.MergePdfPages(pdfPages);

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(finalPdfBytes);

            return File(memoryStream, "application/pdf", "output.pdf");

        }
        catch (NoFileProviderException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while generating the PDF");
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does server know the number of files that will be received?  Does server need to combine files all at one time or can server append each file to the pdf one at a time?  You first have to understand the requirements before you start to code the solution.

Comment: @jdweng Server dont know how many files he will get. Now my code grab all chunks and for every chunk it will generate separated PDF, but i want to generate one PDF for all chunks.

Comment: The requester needs to tell your server whether it already finished or there's more.

Comment: My teammate(requester) created an header to the chunks and the last chunk has Header: "Chunk-End".  Maybe i should work with this? @XiangWeiHuang

Comment: A proper idea of doing this is requester gets an unique id from server first, then you continue talking with that Id, so you can distinguish which pdf are you appending. Otherwise, things will get messy if there are multiple requests going on.

Comment: Is the `GeneratePdfFromSvgFile` method thread-safe?